# Authorize.net error in magento 2.0.5

Tags: magento, authorize.net

I have configured the `authorize.net` in my new magento 2.0.5. I have updated my sandbox `api login id`, `transaction key`, `merchant md5`, and changed the url into https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll for testing.

Also i have enabled the test mode and debug mode to track.  While placing the order I'm receiving the  error on alert box `Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment.`. While checking `/var/log/debug.log` `transaction id` (`x_trans_id`) was in `0`. I suspect that the issue is with the `transaction id`.

Comment: You should not set your gateway to test mode or set test mode as true in your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You should not set your gateway to test mode or set test mode as true in your request.

Comment: based on what documentation?

Comment: @dchayka If you set the sandbox to test mode, or set test mode as true in your request, you are instructing the gateway to only confirm credentials and return OK.  It does not attempt a transaction and nothing is stored at the gateway which is confirmed by a transaction id of zero.

Comment: @rhldr as like your comment we are tried to test the payment with test mode. So we have enabled the test mode => enable in our request and test mode on in our sandbox account. But gateway is not returning as "OK" and its returning an error as "Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment". Please check the below case and let us know will the test mode is working in magento 2.1.1

Test mode enabled + Sandbox account+ Sandbox in test mode + Test gateway url.